# Are my answers just meh or are they being overlooked by Winter Bash excitement?

Tags: discussion, answer-quality

I've answered 9 questions here in December and all but one are at zero score.

Zero score with no comments:

- [Why ping results varied with the CPU load](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722171)
- [e2fsck deletes many inodes, recovers too little data from a disk image. Are there better methods?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728594)
- [Slow boot time, and sometimes slow disk retrieval](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729536)
- [what target flag should I set to cross compile arm 32 bit code in gcc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729537)
- [How to copy files from one machine to another using ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729576)
- [How can I monitor disk io?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729579)

Zero score with some comments:

- [ZFS pool free space discrepancy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729541)
- [Adding missing zeroes in the begining of each line where is less than 4 signs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/729573)

Score of 1 with no comments:

- [Special char in password for smb mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/726955)

Should I step away from answering and learn a bit more about how to answer better here?
Is it related to increased/decreased traffic from Winter Bash?

Comment: At least for the scp one, `sftp` is already covered in at least one other answer there, so I don't see any point of having yet another answer mentioning it.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed that but there seemed to be an issue with it. I tried their sftp advice and it didn’t work on 8.8.

Comment: What didn't work exactly? Also: why not edit it to fix it then? As it stands, I don't see how anything in your answer could be all that different from anything the answer does.